# What is the simplest way to get screenshot in android using kotlin?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-bitmap

I have an imageView and several textViews 
My app allows user to drag textViews on evey coordinates of  imageView **(imageView is not full screen)** that user wants .

In other words this app allows user to add several captions to user image 
and convert that image and captions to a **single** image and store it on user device.

According to one of **stackOverFlow** responses I can just convert one **textView** text to a bitamp

id there any way to screenshot from final image which user have created with its captions  in kotlin??

This is my code:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun foo(text: String) {
    val textPaint = object : Paint() {
        init {
            setColor(Color.WHITE)
            setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)
            setTextSize(20f)
            setAntiAlias(true)

        }
    }
    val bounds = Rect()
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)

    val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImgBanner.getWidth(), mImgBanner.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) //use ARGB_8888 for better quality
    val canvas = Canvas(bmp)
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, 20f, textPaint)
    val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/image.png"
    val stream = FileOutputStream(path)
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    bmp.recycle()
    stream.close()
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What is the problem? Does this code doesn't work?

Comment: i want to make a single bitmap with one imageView and several textViewView on imageView  .That's it

Comment: You need to a viewgroup where your Imageview and textview as child and when you want to create bitmap you need to pass viewgroup to your function that's create your bitmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add desired views in xml layout inflate it and take screenshot of parent layout that is containing your views.

Code for taking screenshoot:

```
 fun takeScreenshotOfView(view: View, height: Int, width: Int): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val bgDrawable = view.background
    if (bgDrawable != null) {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas)
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

Comment: my imageView and textViews  parent layout is a RelativeLayout . And  imageView is not fullscreen how can i put textViews and imageView in a viewGroup ..Shoud i do it in code or layout ? how? 
I try but I can't

Comment: I would suggest to use ConstraintLayout. In ypur layout xml file of fragmant or activity place desired views and in you fragment/activity code take a scrennshot of inflated view, I think taking screenshot in onResume() should work

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the extension View.drawToBitmap(). It will return a Bitmap

```
/**
 * Return a [Bitmap] representation of this [View].
 *
 * The resulting bitmap will be the same width and height as this view's current layout
 * dimensions. This does not take into account any transformations such as scale or translation.
 *
 * Note, this will use the software rendering pipeline to draw the view to the bitmap. This may
 * result with different drawing to what is rendered on a hardware accelerated canvas (such as
 * the device screen).
 *
 * If this view has not been laid out this method will throw a [IllegalStateException].
 *
 * @param config Bitmap config of the desired bitmap. Defaults to [Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888].
 */
fun View.drawToBitmap(config: Bitmap.Config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888): Bitmap {
    if (!ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this)) {
        throw IllegalStateException("View needs to be laid out before calling drawToBitmap()")
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config).applyCanvas {
        translate(-scrollX.toFloat(), -scrollY.toFloat())
        draw(this)
    }
}
```