# What is the best way to capture screenshots programmatically in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-development

I went through few suggestions by the developers here. [What is the simplest way to get screenshot in android using kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591950/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-screenshot-in-android-using-kotlin)
Some says, this canvas and drawingCache based approach is old and it seems there are some issues with it like capturing Dark/Black screenshots.
Some have suggested a method based on the PixelCopy API. What is the most suitable approach for this? For device using Android 10 or higher versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I'm currently using in a project, I'm taking the screenshot from the activity as a bitmap in this case:

```
val bitmap = this.window.decorView.rootView.drawToBitmap(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
```

Keep in mind that if the device is Hardware Accelerated, probably the mentioned code will not work and you will need to implement PixelCopy solutions. I attach a [medium post](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/how-to-programmatically-take-screenshots-with-androids-pixelcopy-api-259d70667360) that might help in that case.